# When using optional arguments when is it best to use **kwargs and best to use keywords?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

If I had a function that had three or four optional keyword arguments is it best to use **kwargs or to specify them in the function definition?

I feel as 
`def foo(required, option1=False, option2=False, option3=True)`
is much more clumsy looking than
`def foo(required, **kwargs)`.

However if I need to use these keywords as conditionals and they don't exist I will have KeyErrors being thrown and I feel like checking for the keys before each conditional is a bit messy.

```py
def foo(required, **kwargs):
    print(required)
    if 'true' in kwargs and kwargs['true']:
        print(kwargs['true'])

foo('test', true='True')
foo('test2')
```

vs

```py
def foo(required, true=None):
    print(required)
    if true:
        print(true)

foo('test', true='True')
foo('test2')
```

I am wondering what the most pythonic way is. I've got a function that I am working on that depending on the parameters passed will return different values so I am wondering the best way to handle it. It works now, but I wonder if there is a better and more pythonic way of handling it.

Comment: You could decorate your function with one that configure the missing arguments so you don't have to check every time.

Comment: You can use `kwargs.get()` to check whether they were passed and obtain their value if they were or provide a default value when they weren't — so just using `kwargs` is fine.

Comment: @dcg if I did that wouldn't I need a decorator per function, if I had multiple functions that had these conditional arguments?

Comment: @Jordan you can implement only one and pass in the defaults at the time of decoration. Something like `@configure(a=1, b=2)`

Comment: Which do you care more about: having a short argument list, or having an *informative* argument list, one that will let people know what arguments your function has? How about error handling? Do you want people who make a typo to get an exception, or do you want the error to pass silently?

Comment: Use the first one if you need *specific* arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function is only using the parameters in its own operation, you should list them all explicitly. This will allow Python to detect if an invalid argument was provided in a call to your function.

You use `**kwargs` when you need to accept dynamic parameters, often because you're passing them along to other functions and you want your function to accept any arguments that the other function needs, e.g. `other_func(**kwargs)`

Comment: If I were to just have keyword arguments is it frowned upon to have option keywords set to specific values if those parameters are used like that more often? For example if I wanted a function to return a dataframe with its input variables merged with their outputs more often than not I'd probably have a parameter that says `merge=True` in the function definition so I don't have to type it out each time, If I don't want that to happen I'd just pass that parameter with False instead and it would return two values instead.

Comment: No, specifying default values is recommended, especially if you have lots of parameters.

Comment: Take a look at the standard Python libraries, they use that style extensively.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to pass in several optional parameters while keeping your function definition clean is to use a dictionary that contains all the parameters. That way your function becomes

```py
def foo(required, params):
    print(required)
    if 'true' in params and params['true']:
        print(params['true'])
```

You really want to use `**kwargs` if your parameters can be anything and you don't really care, such as for a decorator function. If you're actually going to use the parameters in the function, you should specify them explicitly.